# VSTO: Drawing on top of Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, highlighting, worksheet

I've written a bunch of handy Excel add-ins in C#, and everything works great. But the one thing I haven't been able to figure out is if it's possible to place graphics (bitmaps, shapes, whatever) on a worksheet control, e.g. by appending a function to its paint event handler.

I don't want to actually change the document in any way, it's only for temporarily highlighting things to indicate how my add-ins are finding and interpreting data in the sheet. The simplest thing I want to be able to do is draw a border around a specific range.

I could do it by creating a bunch of transparent top-level windows that try to clip themselves to the document window, but that's really a nasty solution, and I'm thinking the windows would get in the way of user input, too.

Comment: Why not use the Borders or background colors of the range? Adding drawings sounds both complex and fragile.

Comment: Because I don't want to change anything in the spreadsheet. I only want to illustrate how my add-in has chosen to interpret data in the worksheet. For one thing, editing the sheet can cause the add-in to recoonsider its interpretation, and that means you'd have the add-in trying to change the sheet while the user is doing the same. And what if the sheet already contains borders and background colours?

Comment: @ReturningTarzan Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

It's late answer, but for future readers I think it's worth to clarify. There is no way to use paint event to draw anything on the top of Excel. But there is built in way to highlight a range or many ranges at the same time - just select it from code.