# Colouring Borders for Selected Ranges Temporarily

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, highlighting, excel-addins

I am making an Excel Addin, and am using an input box to allow the user to select ranges to be exported.  The selection process works well, but I am hoping to display which cells are currently used by implemented a coloured border around used ranges (Similar to when doing a sum in Excel, the cells being summed each get assigned a different coloured border).

I can't just apply a new border and then clear it, as this will not maintain the previous formatting of the document.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

The following link had very similar goals, but no solution was ever provided

[VSTO: Drawing on top of Excel worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952032/vsto-drawing-on-top-of-excel-worksheet)

Thanks!

Comment: You could remember each cell's old border values and restore them instead of clearing

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I would say you could accomplish this by using conditional formatting to apply the border formatting based upon a cell somewhere else in the workbook and then just change those cells values based upon where the user is in the form...

Comment: @JohnBustos, that's a nice idea!

Comment: You could create a hidden worksheet, copy the range, paste special formats into the hidden range. Draw your border, and do whatever, then copy and paste special the formats back.

Answer (score 0):

How about drawing a shape whose location and size are determined by the range? You can make it transparent with a border of your choosing. There's no need to modify the cell themselves.

Just find the needed coordinates and sizes, call AddShape ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addshape(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addshape%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) and store a reference to it so you could delete it when needed.